# Is there any Ansible remote client for control machine?

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

Ansible unlike chef and puppet uses agent less run .
I would like to know is there any ansible remote client so that we can connect to fleet of ansible control machines to execute ansible playbooks on their respective targets .
I am looking for a command line cliient similar to following

ansible-execute  hostname_of_control_machine username_of_control_machine password_of_control_machine inventory_file playbook_name

Please suggest if any ?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just run Ansible playbook from whatever your "master" control machine is?

Comment: I looking for a way to dynamically provision or control existing ansible masters on the fly so that requests can be handled on priority . That is the actual purpose .

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing preventing you from using Ansible to run Ansible on other machines. The [Python API](http://docs.ansible.com/developing_api.html) might be a good place to start, as you can get programmatic control over the initial Ansible runner.

Comment: Iam looking for a tool that could actually control ansible "control machines" rather than the targets of ansible .

Comment: Yes, that was my understanding as well. I'll try to provide an example playbook and some patterns for managing the control machines.

Comment: Basically, @samvarankashyap, Filip is suggesting that your ansible master calls out to your ansible "slaves" with an ansible `command` action to execute a different ansible run.  However, I doubt in practice you'll actually want to do this; one ansible master should be able to handle many hundreds, perhaps thousands, of hosts.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with SSH

```
ssh username@controlmachine 'ansible-playbook yourPlaybook.yml
```